# Unable to configure fingerprint in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, drivers, bluetooth

I'm using Lenovo Thinkbook. It does have a fingerprint sensor which was working fine in windows but it is not working in Ubuntu now.

**OS Config**

```
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.2 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy
```

**lsusb**

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0489:e0cd Foxconn / Hon Hai Wireless_Device
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 10a5:9800 FPC FPC Sensor Controller L:0002 FW:27.26.23.5
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 30c9:0030 Luxvisions Innotech Limited Integrated Camera
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**fprintd-enroll**

```
Impossible to enroll: GDBus.Error:net.reactivated.Fprint.Error.NoSuchDevice: No devices available
```

I ran these update commands daily.

```
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

The laptop works fine while it was windows. Now a lot of times, I get error like bluetooth not connected, wifi adapter not found, every time I've to restart the system in order to make these basic things work.

What wrong am I doing?

Answer (score 1):

Hello for me it worked to download the FPC FingerPrint Driver for Linux from this page. (Although the version of the laptop is one older than mine, it worked for me)

https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-edge-laptops/thinkpad-e14-gen-4-type-21eb-and-21ec/downloads/driver-list/component?name=Fingerprint%20Reader&id=A4F7592E-3C73-4CCF-ABB9-09549219DFC8

Unzip and execute the two installation scripts insight.

Additionally it might be necessary if you have not done so already to first install fprintd.

Afterwards you can enroll your fingerprint, like you tried. Or access the setting in the user settings.